# Adblocker blocks XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, adblock

I understand the fact, that adblockers try to deny loading (image) data later on. Anyway, I want to send some data to a php script (/log.php) to save it in a sql database. So in fact I don't care about the responsetext. This is my current js function I use to call the php script:

```
function log(id, unix_ms, frameid, eventtype, targetid, value){
var parameters = "";
parameters = parameters.concat("id=", encodeURI(id), "&unix_ms=", encodeURI(unix_ms), "&frameid=", encodeURI(frameid), "&eventtype=", eventtype, "&targetid=", targetid, "&value=", value);

var httprequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httprequest.open("POST", "/scripts/log.php", true);
httprequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
httprequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(httprequest.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        console.log(httprequest.responseText);
    }
}
httprequest.send(parameters);
}
```

What can I change to pass the adblocker? I mean facebook uses things like ajax in masses to load text and even images in the timeline.

Is there maybe a way to use frames in the background since I don't care about the answer?

Comment: Which adblocker are you using? Also, it's weird that it is blocking a same-origin request; that shouldn't happen unless your domain has a very suspicious name or something like that

Comment: Yes, I swear it worked a while ago... I am using UBlock Origin. Domain is localhost at the moment.

Comment: UBO comes with a logger (3rd icon on the bottom of its window); did you check that?

Comment: Is the path `/scripts/log.php` the real path, or did you made it up just for the post?

Comment: The path is the actual path.
Log says in red:
13:09:55​ /scripts/log.​ --​ localhost​ 1 ​xhr​http://localhost/scripts/log.php. Furthermore it says it is in the Filterlist easyprivacy.

Comment: Here's my suggestion: 1) turn off adblocking for `localhost` 2) test the code on the actual host

Comment: Thank you Chris, but after finding out log.php was in the filterlist, I changed the name to submitlog.php et voila, no more blocking.

Answer (score 0):

After analysing the log as suggested in a comment I found out that log.php seems to be in the blocklist, even if it's on the same server. So name you php files a little more complex to avoid this.

log.php -> submitlog.php